NextJs Error at build: ApolloError: Dynamic server usage. Couldn't be rendered statically because it used revalidate: 0 fetch
When we build nextJs yarn build when it goes to the step Generating static pages we have this error:
Error occurred prerendering page "/partners/partner-with-us". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ApolloError: Dynamic server usage: Route /partners/partner-with-us couldn't be rendered statically because it used revalidate: 0 fetch http://localhost:4001 /partners/partner-with-us. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/dynamic-server-error

The page partner-with-us is super simple

const PartnerWithUs = () => {
  return <>test</>
}

export default PartnerWithUs


We are using Apollo Graphql for fetching data on other pages. We are using: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs?tab=readme-ov-file#in-client-components-and-streaming-ssr
in the main layout we have
<ApolloWrapper>
  <main>{children}</main>
</ApolloWrapper>

Questions I am trying to solve to fix this issue:

why is he trying to get to the backend for this page partners/partner-with-us ? it is just a basic html page
is he trying to access http://localhost:4001 /partners/partner-with-us? :4001 is the url of the backend, (frontend is :4022)
be rendered statically because it used revalidate: 0 where is this settings?
it says ApolloError: Dynamic server usage it is an apollo (GrpahQl) error?


My problem resulting in "revalidate: 0 fetch" error was that I was fetching data without caching enabled.
const res = await fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/items/${entity}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: this.getHeaders(),
    cache: 'force-cache', // cache on for static generation
    // cache: 'no-store', // cache off
});

My guess is that when no caching mechanism is assured, then SSR breaks, skipping the build step.
Not sure how apollo client can be configured to enable caching, but I would try looking.
